# Prove that in $X = X_1 \cup X_2$ when f restricted to $X_1$ or $X_2$ is continuous for some $x \in X_1 \cap X_2$ then f is also continuous in x

Tags: general-topology

Let $X = X_1 \cup X_2$ and $f: X \to Y$ and $x \in X_1 \cap X_2$. Prove that if $f\restriction_{X_1}$ and $f\restriction_{X_2}$ are continuous in x then $f$ is continuous in x too.

I know that if $f\restriction_{X_1}$ is continuous then $\forall W \subset Y, W \ni f\restriction_{X_1}(x) \text{ } \exists V_1 \subset X, V_1 \ni x$ such that $f\restriction_{X_1}(V_1) \subset W$. The same applies to $f\restriction_{X_2}$ and some $V_2$.

Does that automatically imply that $f(x) \in W_1 \cap W_2$ so there are $V_1 \cap V_2$ such that $f(V_1 \cap V_2) \subset W_1 \cap W_2$ and f is thus continuous in x? I think it is not really a proof - could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Yo do not need different $W_1,W_2$, just one $W$, so $f(V_1\cap V_2)\subset W$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found open neighborhoods $V_i \subset X$ of $x$ auch that $f_i(V_i \cap X_i) \subset W$. Define $V = V_1 \cap V_2$. This is an open neigborhood of $x$ such that
$$f(V) = f((V \cap X_1) \cup (V  \cap X_2)) = f(V \cap X_1) \cup f(V  \cap X_2) = f_1(V \cap X_1) \cup f_2(V  \cap X_2) \\ \subset f_1(V_1 \cap X_1) \cup f_2(V_2 \cap X_2) \subset W .$$